# Django filters to generates filter for list of items

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-filter

I want to filter the field vehicle_type based on comma  query params

```
{{url}}/vehicles-records-info/75d9ee1b-8a03-4697-82e7-2d96ef0a8c2d/?vehicle_type=Mixer,Lorry
```

However when I print the query the generated query is

```
...  AND "vehicle_type" IN (M, i, x, e, r, ,, L, o, y))
```

But the query should be

```
...  AND "vehicle_type" IN ('Mixer', 'Lorry'))
```

Here are my code

**Filter**

````
class VehicularAccessRecordInformationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    vehicle_type = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='vehicle_type', lookup_expr='in')
    start_timestamp = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='timestamp', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_timestamp = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='timestamp', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = VehicleAccessRecordInformation
        fields = ['vehicle_type', 'timestamp']
    ```
````

Comment: try `JSON.stringify` if using javascript before passing list in url and in views do `json.loads()` and filter.

Comment: can you show your views too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class CharInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    pass


class VehicularAccessRecordInformationFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    vehicle_type = CharInFilter(field_name='vehicle_type')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = VehicleAccessRecordInformation
        fields = ['vehicle_type', <other_fields>]
```

`BaseInFilter` accepts multiple values separated by comma, and `CharFilter` defines a type for the values, i.e. you can use `NumberFilter`, `ChoiceFilter`, etc.

So that `?vehicle_type=Mixer,Lorry` evaluates to

```
VehicleAccessRecordInformation.objects.filter(vehicle_type__in=['Mixer', 'Lorry']
```